# Copy object on Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I'm having two `ListBoxes`, both having their `ItemsSource` bound to separate `ObservableCollection<ICustomObject>`. `ICustomObject` is an interface defining some base-properties for different types of `CustomObject`.

I want one `ListBox` to be the static, non changing source of possible elements from where the user can drag them to the other `ListBox` multiple times. Also elements in the target should be rearrangeable.

Result should be a toolbox from where the user can build a document composed of multiple `CustomObject`.

I'm using the [GongSolutions.WPF.DragDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) library for this, commit  [c680fcf](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/commit/c680fcfe37cc7e8f4c7dd61093a8dca69a8da67a).

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableElements}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.DragDropCopyKeyState="ControlKey">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedElements}" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Having this I can copy elements from source to target by holding the ControlKey.

But there are two problems with this:

- Is there any way to default to copy-action, so that no key needs to be pressed?
- How can I do a real copy? Currently all list-elements of the target-list are pointing to the same object with the result that changing the properties of individual elements is not possible.

I already tried it with a custom `DropHandler` but this makes reordering the elements impossible:

```
public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    IFormElement data = Activator.CreateInstance(dropInfo.Data.GetType()) as IFormElement;
    if (data != null)
    {
        SelectedElements.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Any help and hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed Wills answer and created my own drop handler based on the default drop handler. This way I could overwrite the default behavior to be always copy but not within the same list.

Looking at the default code I also found that its trying to clone the objects on copy, if they implement `ICloneable`. So I made them cloneable returning a new instance of them self.

Here are the relevant parts of the code (DropHandler-code mostly based on original [DefaultDropHandler.cs](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/blob/master/GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop/DefaultDropHandler.cs)):

**View.xaml:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableElements}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedElements}" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**ViewModel.cs** (must implement `IDropTarget`)

```
public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    DragDrop.DefaultDropHandler.DragOver(dropInfo);
}

public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
{
    if (dropInfo == null || dropInfo.DragInfo == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var insertIndex = dropInfo.InsertIndex != dropInfo.UnfilteredInsertIndex ? dropInfo.UnfilteredInsertIndex : dropInfo.InsertIndex;
    var destinationList = dropInfo.TargetCollection.TryGetList();
    var data = ExtractData(dropInfo.Data);

    // default to copy but not if source equals target
    var copyData = (!Equals(dropInfo.DragInfo.SourceCollection, dropInfo.TargetCollection)) 
                   && !(dropInfo.DragInfo.SourceItem is HeaderedContentControl)
                   && !(dropInfo.DragInfo.SourceItem is HeaderedItemsControl)
                   && !(dropInfo.DragInfo.SourceItem is ListBoxItem);
    if (!copyData)
    {
        var sourceList = dropInfo.DragInfo.SourceCollection.TryGetList();

        foreach (var o in data)
        {
            var index = sourceList.IndexOf(o);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                sourceList.RemoveAt(index);
                if (Equals(sourceList, destinationList) && index < insertIndex)
                {
                    --insertIndex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var tabControl = dropInfo.VisualTarget as TabControl;

    // clone data but not if source equals target
    var cloneData = !Equals(dropInfo.DragInfo.SourceCollection, dropInfo.TargetCollection); 
    foreach (var o in data)
    {
        var obj2Insert = o;
        if (cloneData)
        {
            var cloneable = o as ICloneable;
            if (cloneable != null)
            {
                obj2Insert = cloneable.Clone();
            }
        }

        destinationList.Insert(insertIndex++, obj2Insert);

        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            var container = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj2Insert) as TabItem;
            if (container != null)
            {
                container.ApplyTemplate();
            }

            tabControl.SetSelectedItem(obj2Insert);
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable ExtractData(object data)
{
    if (data is IEnumerable && !(data is string))
    {
        return (IEnumerable)data;
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(data, 1);
    }
}
```

@Will: thanks for your answer, it pointed me in the right direction. To help others I will answer my own question, but I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

"*but this makes reordering the elements impossible*" Why? It shouldn't, unless you're doing something wrong.  To do what you want, a custom handler is the way to go, so you should detail why it wasn't working.

The collection into which you are dropping objects should implement INotifyCollectionChanged in order for the UI to update when you add new items into it.  If that isn't your issue, please edit your question to add details.  Assuming that isn't the problem, I'll suggest an alternative, simpler and sometimes much better alternative.

I recently added drag/drop using this library to my application.  I had to create a custom drop handler as the collection being dropped on contained *relationships to*, not instances of, the class being dragged.

Think of it like a relational database.  You have two tables-- People and Pets.  Pets can be owned by multiple people, and people can have multiple pets.  In a database, you would have a many-to-many table.

People -> PeoplePets <- Pets

PeoplePets describes the relationship between people and their pets, and pets to their people.

In your design, you're literally **cloning** a pet.  Which means you and your girlfriend have two dogs now, both with the same name and both with a strong desire to roll in the neighbor cat's poop.  That's weird (the cloning part, not the poop part), although I'm sure many folks would be happy with this arrangement.

Instead of your collection holding clones of pets, have your collection hold *objects which define the relationship*.

```
public ObservableCollection<PeoplePets> Pets {get;} = 
    new ObservableCollection<PeoplePets>();
```

**And so, to the point of your question**, in your custom drop handler, when someone drops a pet on your listbox, simply create a new instance of PeoplePets, drop the pet in it, and add the relationship object to the collection.  You don't have to worry about cloning anything, and you won't be adding new instances of the same thing (this can be extremely helpful, depending on what you're doing with the data down the road--detecting and merging dupes is a PITA).

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your second question. To do a real copy you can use the following class or just use the cloning part in your code:

```
public class GenericCloner<T> where T : class
{
    public T Clone(T obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
}
```